# Why I don't get a CGContextRef

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios-4.2

I try to get a CGContextRef from UIImage. Always my CGContextRef is 0x0 in Debugger.

Here is the code:

```
NSString *movName = imgName;
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:movName ofType:@"png"];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

        CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
        CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceInfo = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);

        CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, 
                                                    100, 
                                                    100, 
                                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), 
                                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), 
                                                    colorSpaceInfo, 
                                                    bitmapInfo);
```

thank you for answering

Comment: good question... I try this because my UIImage *image, which I scratch from disk, have a size of 768x944 (and this is the size I have to show it on screen) and because of this big I have problems with the memory. I try many workarounds and come to this with the bitmap. Maybe you have an idea about CGLayer and his use of memeory?

Comment: It sounds like real the problem you are having lies elsewhere. Any current Apple device should be able to handle loading and displaying a 768x944 image with little or no difficulty. The code above is trying to create a blank 100x100 bitmap, which I do not think is what you want either. Even if you did change the size. a UIImage is using a CGImage behind the scenes so you're still back where you started. I would take a look at the rest of your program and see if there might be another solution.

Comment: @fbrereto: the 100x100 is only for testing, but theCGBitmapContextCreate() returns NULL to me. And yes it is possible to loading and displaying an image with 768x944, but this increases the memory much more than an image with, lets say, 50x50. If I load and release 10 (or more) images my memory is going to knees, because it seems the release of the image never freed the memory.

Comment: If you release all ownership of the image it should deallocate. The only reason the image would still be resident in memory is because the OS thinks an object is still retaining it. Also, is it possible to resize the image resources themselves so you don't have to at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

The NULL result is detailed in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html):

> Return Value:
>   A new bitmap context, or NULL if a context could not be created

I would start by investigating the parameters you are passing to the function. It is possible the source image isn't being loaded properly. Have you tried debugging this code? What does the debugger tell you?

Comment: The image is loaded. But what means properly? Here are the parameters that I passing: CGImageGetBitsPerComponent = 8, CGImageGetBytesPerRow = 576, colorSpaceInfo = kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB, bitmapInfo = 5.